# Объекты в Canvas перекрываются объектами вне Canvas. Как это исправить?

Tags: c#, unity3d, canvas, 2d

[image]

Собственно проблема на скрине.

Comment: Читаем [документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-Canvas.html). В 99 случаев из 100 вы найдёте там ответ. Или [там](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/) если это касается не `Unity`,а языка.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно у тебя Canvas в режиме World Space. В этом режиме ты волен двигать его , как и все остальные 3d объекты.

В твоём случае, если тебе надо просто те кнопки управления разместить, вполне подойдет Screen Space-Overlay, который будет рендерить UI поверх всего.

Может быть и вообще дикость. Типа, если ты рендеришь свою игру на текстуру, и потом эту текстуру вставил, как Raw Image, в свой Canvas с порядком выше, чем порядок твоих кнопок. (Последнее вообще бред в твоём случае. Но, я не знаю, что именно у тебя)